How can I extract the constant coefficient in polynomial?
I have an equation with this form: eq1 = 0.38*u1[t] + 0.285*u1[t]*v1[t] + 0.85*u1[t]^2.
I want to extract the coefficient of u1[t] without 0.285*v1[t]. How can I do that?
eq1 = 0.38*u1[t] + 0.285*u1[t]*v1[t] + 0.85*u1[t]^2;
Coefficient[eq1, u1[t]]

(* 0.38 + 0.285 v1[t] *)


Cases[Coefficient[eq1, u1[t]], _?NumericQ]

also you could try Cases[Coefficient[eq1, u1[t]], x_ /; FreeQ[x, _Symbol]] and see if this works for all cases you might have.

Treat it as a polynomial in two variables and look for the (1,0) coefficient (i.e., the prefactor of $u_1(t)^1 \times v_1(t)^0$):
eq1 = 0.38*u1[t] + 0.285*u1[t]*v1[t] + 0.85*u1[t]^2;

Variables[eq1]
(*    {u1[t], v1[t]}    *)

{1, 0} /. CoefficientRules[eq1, Variables[eq1]]
(*    0.38    *)


Instead of trying to extract the number with Coefficient and filtering the result, it is much better to go the mathematical way. Your function can be written as
$$
f(u, v) = f_{0,0}+f_{10}u^1+f_{0,1}v^1+f_{2,0}u^2+f_{1,1}u^1v^1+f_{0,2}v^2+\ldots
$$
You would like to get the $f_{1,0}$ term. Therefore, use series expansion over $v$ to 0th order, bring the result to the normal (polynomial) form and get the desired coefficient:
Coefficient[Series[eq1, {v1[t], 0, 0}] // Normal, u1[t]]


Alternative way:SeriesCoefficient[eq1, {u1[t], 0, 1}, {v1[t], 0, 0}]

Thank you very much for your kindness. Your help solved my problem.

@saboorsavvafi You can accept the answer if it solves your problem and/or upvote it if you like it.

Select[Coefficient[eq1, u1[t]], FreeQ[t]]

(* 0.38 *)

